# Does jQuery have a similar method to Dojo when it comes to Profiles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am trying to devise a system like Dojo's Profile build system in jQuery. Is there anything out there like that for jQuery?

Comment: If your web app is complicated enough to require a build system, then probably you should switch to Dojo, which is optimized for large, enterprise-level apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery does not have its own loader or package system, but you should look at [requirejs](http://requirejs.org) which uses AMD format to declare dependencies and manage large numbers of modules and works with a variety of toolkits.  there's also [labjs](http://labjs.com) which takes a simpler approach to concatenate files.